How to specify link names for sections make4ht/tex4ht LaTeX to HTML
When converting a LaTeX file to HTML, how can I specify the names assigned to the links to sections automatically generated by the tex4ht wrapper make4ht?
Consider the following minimal example of LaTeX file with two section labelled with \label{} and a Table of Contents
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}\label{sec:intro}

This is my introduction.

\section{Results}\label{sec:results}

Here are the results.

\end{document}

When I convert it to HTML5 as follows
make4ht example.tex

The HTML output for the Table of Contents looks like this, with link to the two sections called #x1-20001 and #x1-30002.
   <div class='tableofcontents'>
   <span class='sectionToc'>1 <a href='#x1-20001' id='QQ2-1-2'>Introduction</a></span><br/>   
   <span class='sectionToc'>2 <a href='#x1-30002' id='QQ2-1-3'>Results</a></span>
   </div>

If I compile the same file with Pandoc as follows
pandoc example.tex -f latex -t html5 -s -o example.html --toc

The HTML output for the Table of Contents looks like this, with link to the two sections called #sec:intro and #sec:results, like the labels that I specified in the LaTeX file
<ul>
<li><a href="#sec:intro" id="toc-sec:intro">Introduction</a></li>
<li><a href="#sec:results" id="toc-sec:results">Results</a></li>
</ul>

How can I have make4ht generate specific labels like Pandoc?
Having fixed labels can be very useful when re-organizing sections because links from external pages to sections of my website stop working if the link names change.

Do you use up-to-date TeX Live? Recent make4ht versions assign IDs for sections based on titles. For your MWE, it creates <span class='sectionToc'>1 <a href='#introduction' id='QQ2-1-2'>Introduction</a></span>.

I have MikTeX. I made sure my MikTeX is up-to-date. It says that make4ht was "Packaged on" 27/02/2024. No updates are available on MikTeX.

This version should work, so that's strange. Do you get any warnings about XML and DOM parsing?

I get these warnings [WARNING] tocid: char-def module not found; [WARNING] tocid: cannot fix section id's

Ah, so this is the issue! The char-def module is needed for this to work. It is part of ConTeXt, but I am not sure if it is possible to install ConTeXt  with MikTeX. I will try to change this dependency.

make4ht sets the ID in sections based on the title text. Since it needs to remove diacritics and characters that are not letters, it loads Unicode data contained in the char-def.lua file. This file is part of the ConTeXt distribution and is included in TeX Live. However, you are using MikTeX, and it seems that it is not available there. Therefore, I have added a simplified version of this file to the development version of make4ht, which eliminates this dependency, ensuring that text cleaning will work in all distributions.
Your MWE produces a following result:
<h3 class='likesectionHead' id='contents'><a id='x1-1000'></a>Contents</h3>
   <div class='tableofcontents'>
   <span class='sectionToc'>1 <a href='#introduction' id='QQ2-1-2'>Introduction</a></span>
<br />   <span class='sectionToc'>2 <a href='#results' id='QQ2-1-3'>Results</a></span>
   </div>
<!-- l. 7 --><p class='noindent'>
</p>
   <h3 class='sectionHead' id='introduction'><span class='titlemark'>1   </span> <a id='x1-20001'></a>Introduction</h3>
<!-- l. 9 --><p class='noindent'>This is my introduction.
</p><!-- l. 11 --><p class='noindent'>
</p>
   <h3 class='sectionHead' id='results'><span class='titlemark'>2   </span> <a id='x1-30002'></a>Results</h3>
<!-- l. 13 --><p class='noindent'>Here are the results.
</p>


Thanks a lot! I don't know how to install a development version, but I hope it will become available in the MikTeX package manager soon.

@divenex I hope to post the update to CTAN soon, so it should be available in MikTeX afterwards.
